# SQL - Using a parameter where a String is required

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a parameter in a procedure, which allows the user to include the file location of a JSON file to use. My issue is that, SQL does not allow me to use the parameter, giving me the error:

> Cannot bulk load. The file "@JSONFileLocation" does not exist.

and also when attempting to remove the '', the error:

> Expecting STRING or TEXT_LEX.

This is the complete procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE main.mainRun @JSONFileLocation NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN TRY

DECLARE @Details NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Details = 
    BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK @JSONFileLocation ,SINGLE_CLOB) JSON

    INSERT INTO main.jsontable (dateloaded,name,surname,email,age,balance,country,registered)
    (SELECT GETDATE(), [Name],[Surname],[Email],[Age],[Balance],[Country],[Registered]
    FROM OPENJSON(@Details,'$.PersonDetails.Person')        
    WITH(
        [Name] NVARCHAR(50)         '$.first_name',
        [Surname] NVARCHAR(50)      '$.last_name',
        [Email] NVARCHAR(50)        '$.email',
        [Age] NVARCHAR(50)          '$.age',
        [Balance] NVARCHAR(50)      '$.balance',
        [Country] NVARCHAR(50)      '$.country',
        [Registered] NVARCHAR(50)   '$.registered'
        )
    )

    EXEC main.generateStatistics

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT  
        CONCAT('Error Number:',ERROR_NUMBER(),'|Error Message:',ERROR_MESSAGE(),'|Error Procedure:',ERROR_PROCEDURE()) AS 'Error'
    END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your OPENROWSET query. You need to use Dynamic Sql to pass Path as a parameter to OPENROWSET. Something like...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE main.mainRun 
    @JSONFileLocation NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

    DECLARE   @Details  NVARCHAR(MAX)
            , @Sql      NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @Sql = N' SELECT @Details = BulkColumn
                  FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @JSONFileLocation + ''',SINGLE_CLOB) JSON;';

    Exec sp_executesql @Sql
                      , N'@Details  NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'
                      , @Details OUTPUT;

    INSERT INTO main.jsontable
                       (dateloaded,name,surname,email,age,balance,country,registered)
    SELECT GETDATE(), [Name],[Surname],[Email],[Age],[Balance],[Country],[Registered]
    FROM OPENJSON(@Details,'$.PersonDetails.Person')        
    WITH(
        [Name]      NVARCHAR(50)    '$.first_name',
        [Surname]   NVARCHAR(50)    '$.last_name',
        [Email]     NVARCHAR(50)    '$.email',
        [Age]       NVARCHAR(50)    '$.age',
        [Balance]   NVARCHAR(50)    '$.balance',
        [Country]   NVARCHAR(50)    '$.country',
        [Registered] NVARCHAR(50)   '$.registered'
        )

    EXEC main.generateStatistics;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT  
        CONCAT  ('Error Number:',ERROR_NUMBER()
                ,'|Error Message:',ERROR_MESSAGE()
                ,'|Error Procedure:',ERROR_PROCEDURE()) AS 'Error'
    END CATCH

END
```

Comment: Hmm I see, what exactly does SP Execute do?

Comment: This worked perfectly thankyou!!  I applied this to XML as follows:


    `DECLARE @InXMLPath VARCHAR(250);
    DECLARE @xmlData XML
        , @ORS NVARCHAR(MAX);

 SET @InXMLPath = 'C:\myxmlfile.xml';
 SET @ORS = N'SELECT @xmlData = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET (
  BULK ''' + @InXMLPath + ''', SINGLE_CLOB
   ) AS xmlData;';

    Exec sp_executesql @ORS
                      , N'@xmlData XML OUTPUT'
                      , @xmlData OUTPUT;`